# anchored + by/in/on/to

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions

I've seen many research papers that used the four prepositions quite interchangeably after the verb *anchor*, specifically in this sentence:

> This study is anchored by/in/on/to the theory (or concept) of X.

Are they really interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.

- Anchored *by* - the theory attaches your study to some bigger entity, it's a fundamental part of your study that makes it extend existing research and not exist by itself separately and the theory is a part that is the link.
- Anchored *in* - the study is a part of the theory, a significant element of it.
- Anchored *to* (and possibly, but not really as neatly *on*) - the study is attached to the theory - there is some link between your study and the theory.

> *The Pythagorean Theorem* is anchored **by** the *trigonometric one theorem* **to** *trigonometry* in general, **in** the wide domain of *geometry*.

Comment: ". . . _it_'s a fundamental part of your study that makes _it_ extend existing research . . ."

I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, but does the first _it_ refer to the entity or the theory; how about the second _it_?

Comment: @Sherlock: Think of ships. Ship anchored *by* anchor *to* harbor *in* a port. The anchor is a part of the ship. (first "it" refers to the theory, the other to the study.)